# Table join in mysql returning null

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two tables in mysql, when I tried to join these two tables based on common columns, it returned null, even when values in the columns in both these tables were same.

```
Table_1 structure :

id                VARCHAR (!2) - index
string1           VARCHAR (15)
string2           VARCHAR (50)
string3           VARCHAR (20)
city              VARCHAR (50)
zip               VARCHAR (20)


Table_2 structure :


string1           VARCHAR (15) -- index
string2           VARCHAR (50) -- index 
string3           VARCHAR (20)
city              VARCHAR (50)
zip               VARCHAR (20)
id_1              int (6)
```

I used the query:

```
SELECT p.id, pr.id_1
  FROM table_1 as p 
   LEFT JOIN table_2 as pr
    ON p.string1 = pr.string1
     AND p.string2 = pr.string2 
     AND p.city = pr.city 
     AND p.zip = pr.zip
```

This query is returning NULLs for id_1. Most of the rows are having the same data for the columns compared in both these tables, I am not understanding why this is happening. Can someone please tell me why this is happening and why this is happening.

The data model:

table_1

```
id_1    string1     string2    string3    city    zip
 1      abc          cde          efg      ghi     00001-13
 2      cde          efg          abc      abc     00002     

id_2    string1     string2    string3    city    zip
 3      abc          cde          efg      ghi     00001-13
 4      cde          efg          abc      abc     00002
```

The result expected:

```
id_1    id_2
 1      3
 2      4
```

The result obtained:

```
id_1    id_2    
 1      null
 2      null
```

Comment: Where does the `pr` part get defined in your query?

Comment: Look at your join. you are saying p.string1 = pr.string1. THis is fine; but look at the next part after your and. p.string1 = pr.string2.  both those cant be validated. Did you mean p.string2 = pr.string2

Comment: You should edit the question to put the `pr` alias after `table2`.

Comment: @italianStalion sorry for the typos, have edited the query.

Comment: @RahulNair . . . The data may look the same, but there might be hidden characters or leading spaces that prevent the match.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How will i find out if there are any hidden characters, how the table_2 was populated was to parse the table_1 table using ruby to get all the columns except for the p.id and store the values to table_2, thus technically both of these are same data except for the ids. So I am not able to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id, pr.id_1
  FROM table_1 as p 
   LEFT JOIN table_2 as pr
    ON p.string1 = pr.string1
     AND p.string1 = pr.string2 
     AND p.city = pr.city 
     AND p.zip = pr.zip
```

I no see any problem in this query

[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/215893/1)

Comment: That is why this is not a simple issue, I just cant figure out what is going on.

Comment: @RahulNair Dump Your Tables(Data & Structure) In Here

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, pr.id_1
  FROM table_1 as p 
   LEFT JOIN table_2 as pr
    ON p.string1 = pr.string1
     AND p.string2 = pr.string2 
     AND p.city = pr.city 
     AND p.zip = pr.zip;
```

this query is hundred percent correct. there was no reason for wrong output.

Comment: that is what confuses me, do you know of any way to check if any of these columns are having any hidden characters, or any other tool to compare data in both these tables.

Comment: yes, It should be possibility may be some hidden spaces there.